# is it possible to define a set function for module variables in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I found that you can do a get function in node.js like so

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "g_myvar", {
 get: function() { return g_myvar; }
});
```

so maybe you can do a set function like so

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "g_myvar", {
 set: function(val) { g_myvar = val; }
});
```

but both exports functions have the same name so that's not going to work. I suppose I could have a function with a different name but that means changing all the variable assignments to function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine them:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "g_myvar", {
  get: function() { return g_myvar; },
  set: function(val) { g_myvar = val; }   
});
```

Comment: this does the job nicely!

Answer (score 0):

in your module just do

```
module.exports = {
   mySetter: function (value) {...},
   myGetter: function () {return ...}
};
```

and than you can use your module everywhere like

```
var myModule = require('my-module);
myModule.mySetter(...)
myModule.myGetter(...)
```

and so on....

or maybe i didn't understand the question.